# Signal Conversion in C

Tags: microcontroller, c, signal

So I have a 32 bit Float data type that represents a value of Ohms. I need to convert that signal to a 8 bit unsigned data type that represents mOhms, where 1mOhm per bit. Does anyone have any ideas how I can solve this? thanks everyone.

Comment: "each bit equals a mOhm", this is a bit confusing. Are you trying to say for example: 0b00110011 is 4mOhms or 51mOhms?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use a typecast:

```
/* ... */
float fres;
unsigned char ires_mohm;

fres = get_resistance();
ires_mohm = (unsigned char)((1000 * fres)+0.5);
/* ... */
```

The added "0.5" is because float to integer conversion is done by truncation rather than rounding.

You would also want to do some error checking in case the floating point value is less than 0 or greater than 0.2554.

Comment: `[...]to a 8 bit unsigned data type[...]`

Comment: @m.Alin, good point.